# Convert categorical variables from String to int representation

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a numpy array of classification of text in the form of String array, i.e. 
`y_train = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C',...]`. I am trying to apply SKlearn multinomial NB algorithm to predict classes for entire dataset.

I want to convert the String classes into integers to be able to input into the algorithm and convert `['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', ...]` into `['1', '2', '1', '3', ...]`

I can write a for loop to go through array and create a new one with int classifiers but is there a direct function to achieve this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using sklearn, I would suggest sticking with methods in that library that do these things for you. Sklearn has a number of ways of preprocessing data such as encoding labels. One of which is the `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` function.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder  

le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit_transform(y_train)
```

Which outputs

```
array([0, 1, 0, 2])
```

Use `le.inverse_transform([0,1,2])` to map back

Comment: Does this create unique labels for 'abc' and 'bac' and 'cba'?

Answer (score 19):

Try [factorize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) method:

```
In [264]: y_train = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'A', 'C'])

In [265]: y_train
Out[265]:
0    A
1    B
2    A
3    C
dtype: object

In [266]: pd.factorize(y_train)
Out[266]: (array([0, 1, 0, 2], dtype=int64), Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object'))
```

Demo:

```
In [271]: fct = pd.factorize(y_train)[0]+1

In [272]: fct
Out[272]: array([1, 2, 1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: this doesnt seem as though it will be constant/unique between calls.  for example if i make two call with the same data, but differently ordered in the 2 different dataframes.

Answer (score 12):

Another way is use the astype('category').cat.codes of the dataframe to convert the string values into number

```
X=df[['User ID', 'Gender', 'Age', 'EstimatedSalary']]
X['Gender']=X['Gender'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Comment: is this guaranteed to be unique and constant for multiple calls with same strings?

Comment: @mike01010  The codes are definitely unique. I'm not 100% sure about consistency but I believe it assigns the codes based on the strings' alphabetical order so the encoding must be consistent.